Nikon Z50 Live View Not Reflecting Setting Changes (White Balance, ISO, etc.)
I am encountering an issue with the Live View functionality on my Nikon Z50 camera. When adjusting various settings like White Balance, ISO, and potentially others, the changes are not reflected in the Live View preview. However, the adjustments are applied correctly to the final image after the photo is captured.
